# How do I join a Minecraft PE server on PS3?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

How do I join a multiplayer Minecraft Pocket Edition server on Minecraft PE PS3. I am so confused.

Comment: I think you may be confused. Minecraft PE is for mobile platforms, Minecraft on PS3 isn't the PE (Pocket Edition) They're separate version of the game.

Comment: Minecraft PE PS3? I'm so confused too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I play the same world between PS4 and Mobile?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/356965/how-can-i-play-the-same-world-between-ps4-and-mobile)

Comment: All attempts at cross-play between Legacy Console and Bedrock are functionally the same question, regardless of which specific platform each edition is running on. A "needs details or clarity" closure per @QbsidianH20's could also be valid.

Answer (score 7):

You can't—they are separate versions of the game. PE is Pocket Edition and its multiplayer servers are incompatible with other versions of the game.

Answer (score -3):

---

you can't there two totally different games. And their updates don't even come out at the same time so how would you be able to play with a non-updated version of your game. Plus there two totally different versions. Sorry :(

---