# How can I play the same world between PS4 and Mobile?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have Minecraft on my PS4 and mobile device. Is there a way for me to share the world that is on my PS4 account to my mobile so I can play while I’m out and about?

Answer (score 2):

The Bedrock edition of Minecraft, which allows for cross-play with other platforms, is not yet available on PS4. However, source code referencing the PS4 version of Bedrock edition has been discovered, so it is expected that a PS4 release is in development.

Until then, you will not be able to share worlds or cross-play between your PS4 and mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2019, the PlayStation 4 version of the game received an update to enabled cross platform support, as [this article states](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2019-12-09-finally-playstation-gets-cross-platform-minecraft-tomorrow).

The [official Minecraft.net store page for the PlayStation 4](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/store/minecraft-ps4) version also states:

> Cross-platform play for up to eight players across Windows PCs, Android devices, iOS phones and tablets, Xbox Series X|S and Xbox One, Nintendo Switch, PlayStation 4, and virtual reality platforms